# excel shows numbers truncated instead of full format

Tags: excel

I am trying to export an excel file to csv and it exports this number : 680001010091945
as : 6.8E+14 
how do I make it display the full number instead of a truncated one ?
any help ? thank you

Comment: In some cases just expanding the width of the column will do the trick.

Comment: check this link - http://www.infopackets.com/news/carols_corner_office/2006/20060323_display_number_values_greater_than_12_digits_ms_excel.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format column as number with 0 decimal digits.